# Passing values to functions in React Native from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, state

I am extracting data from a JSON Array and creating objects out of it and setting the string values that I need from the array within the objects I am creating using a `for` loop:

```
var gamesList = [];
gamesList = this.props.navigation.state.params.gamesList;
var gameIconList = [];

for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
  var provider = gamesList[i].provider;
  var gameId = gamesList[i].gameId.toString();

  gameIconList.push(
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={(provider,gameId) => this.launchGame(provider,gameId)}>
      <ResponsiveImage source={{uri: gamesList[i].imageUrl}}
      initWidth="200" initHeight="120" defaultSource={require('./splash-tile2.png')} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

This is all happening within the `render()` function and the `{gameIconList}` will be called in the `return()` function as below:

```
return(
 <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
    {gameIconList}
 </ScrollView>
);
```

As you can see I am setting the string values into the onPress function call via the loop and when I click the image within the `TouchableOpacity` I want the string values I am setting to be sent back to the function above which is:

```
  launchGame = (provider, gameId) => {

  params = {
    Provider: provider.nativeEvent.text,
    Platform: this.state.Platform,
    Environment: this.state.Environment,
    GameId: gameId,
    IsDemo: this.state.IsDemo
  };

  request = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: params
  };

}
```

But the problem is I have tried so many different methods and I always end up getting a Proxy object sent back to me when it comes to the provider value and an undefined sent to me when it comes to the gameId value.

I have tried the calling method of `event.target.value` and `event.nativeEvent.text` but to no avail.

What am I missing?
And if this is not the correct way of sending values to the function, can I get a guide on how to do it properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `onPress` prop for `TouchableOpacity` takes a callback function that is called when that element is "pressed".

This function is supposed to be an event handler. It is conventional that an event handler is called with an `event` object. I think you are misunderstanding how callback functions are called. Please go through [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events).

So, your function is called with the event object (proxy event object in React) in the first argument and `undefined` as the second argument.

Do this instead:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.launchGame(provider, gameId)}>
```

But there is more. This probably won't work properly because of how closures work. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

Basically, you are changing the value in `provider` and `gameId` on each loop. The callback functions have these variables in its closure, but they do not store the exact value that was there when these functions were defined (basically, you'll get the last value stored in `provide` and `gameId` when pressing on all of the `TouchableOpacity`). This is also because you are using `var`, instead of `let` or `const`, which had function scope and not block scope.

You can do this instead:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
  var provider = gamesList[i].provider;
  var gameId = gamesList[i].gameId.toString();
  this.launchGame(provider, gameId)
}}>
  <ResponsiveImage
    source={{uri: gamesList[i].imageUrl}}
    initWidth="200"
    initHeight="120"
    defaultSource={require('./splash-tile2.png')}
  />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This way you are defining these variables in each callback's scope directly. (Or, if you can use `let` or `const`, change `var` to `const` when defining `provider` and `gameId` and your code should work.)

Comment: I am getting error on the same function as OP asked, as per this answer after setting ids when I click on it i got the error of `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response.data[i].category')` but the same `response.data[i].category` prints its name on text field into it.

Comment: `onPress={this.launchGame.bind(this,gamesList[i].provider,gamesList[i].gameId)}` worked for me finally :)